# Removing entries from arrays in a parallel manner

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list/array of x and y coordinates, for example:

```
x = [x1, x2, x3,...]
y = [y1, y2, y3,...]
```

Now, I want to remove certain entries based on conditions, for example, the following:

```
for i in x:
    if i <= 40 and i >= -40:
        print "True"
    else:
        x.remove(i)

for i in y:
    if i <= 20 and i >=- 20:
        print "True"
    else:
        y.remove(i)
```

The code above removes the respective entries from the lists, but if `x1` is removed, `y1` still remains in the list. What I want to achieve is, if `x1` is removed, `y1` should also be removed. How can I go about doing this? My final goal is to try to plot `x` and `y`, so I am unable to do this as the lists end up having different dimensions. I can also use

```
zeta_list = np.column_stack((x, y))
```

to get an array like `([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3],...]])`, but I am not sure how to remove entries from this using an if conditional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form a boolean selection mask:

```
mask = ~((x > 40) | (x < -40) | (y > 20) | (y < -20))
```

then, to select values from `x` and `y` where `mask` is True:

```
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
```

---

When `x` is a NumPy array, `(x > 40)` returns a boolean array of the same shape as `x` which is `True` where the elements of `x` are greater than 40.

Note the use of `|` for bitwise-or and `~` for `not` (boolean negation).

---

Alternatively, by [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you could use

```
mask = ((x <= 40) & (x >= -40) & (y <= 20) & (y >= -20))
```

NumPy operations are performed *element-wise*. So `mask` is True whereever an element of `x` is between -40 and 40 *and the corresponding element* of `y` is between -20 and 20.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
x = [-50, -50, 30, 0, 50]
y = [-30, 0, 10, 30, 40]

# change the lists to NumPy arrays
x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
# mask = ~((x > 40) | (x < -40) | (y > 20) | (y < -20))
mask = ((x <= 40) & (x >= -40) & (y <= 20) & (y >= -20))
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
```

yields

```
In [35]: x
Out[35]: array([30])

In [36]: y
Out[36]: array([10])
```

with

```
In [37]: mask
Out[37]: array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I see what you're doing here, but what if I wanted to retain a coordinate like (30,10)? in your method, the list is ordered numerically already right? or would it preserve the coordinates? I really should try it though

Comment: Yes, it is best to try it yourself! However, I changed the example to make it easier to check the correctness of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to work with `list-comprehension`:

*Input*:

```
x = [50, 10, -50, 30, 5, 6]
y = [2, 40, 10, 5, 3, 5]
```

*Code*:

```
x, y = list(zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in zip(x, y) if x <= 40 and x > -40 and y <= 20 and y > -20]))
```

*Output*:

```
x
# (30, 5, 6)

y
# (5, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks! Learnt something new!

Comment: The call to built-in `list()` has no effect on `x` and `y`. Indeed, if you get rid of it the output tuples are exactly the same. If you wish `x`and `y` to be lists you should tweak your code like this: `x, y = map(list, zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in zip(x, y) if x <= 40 and x > -40 and y <= 20 and y > -20]))`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mask = ((x <= 40) & (x >= -40) & (y <= 20) & (y >= -20))
x, y = x[mask], y[mask]
```

NumPy will vectorize these operations, so it should be very efficient.

[This](https://python-astro.blogspot.com/2012/05/playing-with-arrays-slicing-sorting.html) blog post might be helpful, and here's the manual for [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which shows some similar examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was helpful!

Comment: Tried, but i get an error saying TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Ah, your arrays must be in a different shape or type than I was expecting. No problem though, glad it helped. If you show how to create example input arrays I can revise. But I like @unutbu's answer and you should do that :)

Comment: Yeah probably the reason, but this gave me insight into the np.where, yeah will follow his answer!

Comment: I'm afraid this code does not work as the OP expects because you are indexing `x` and `y` differently. The argument of function `where` should be the mask proposed by @unutbu in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
for i in x1:
    if i <= 40 and i >= -40:
        print "True"
        for i in y1:
            if i <=20 and i >=-20:
                print "True"
            else:
                x1.remove(i)
                y1.remove(i)
    else:
        x1.remove(i)
        y1.remove(i)
```

Hope this helped!

Thanks!

Comment: basicly all i did was moved the second for loop into the first, and removed both coordinates when 1 is flase

Comment: I see the logic behind this, but when I tried the code, I get this error, ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: yeah i did not trie it, theres some fualts in it, im trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is a solution based on **itertools**.

Consider the following lists of coordinates:

```
x = [-50, -50, -10,   0,  10, 50, 50, -10, -10, 0, 10, 40]
y = [-50, -20, -50,  50, -50, 20, 50, -20, -10, 0, 20, 10]
```

Our goal is to set-up a boolean mask with the value `True` in those indices `n` for which `x[n]` and `y[n]` lie in certain intervals, and `False` elsewhere. The intervals' boundaries are:

```
xmin, xmax = -40, 40
ymin, ymax = -20, 20
```

We can create such a mask through a list comprehension:

```
mask = [xmin <= i <= xmax and ymin <= j <= ymax for (i, j) in zip(x, y)]
```

The boolean expression `xmin <= i <= xmax and ymin <= j <= ymax` is evaluated for each pair of corresponding coordinates. If both `i` and `j` belong to the specified intervals the expression is evaluated as `True`, and `False` otherwise. The fact that comparisons can be chained in Python makes this boolean expression pretty compact and readable.

Finally, we can get rid of those coordinate pairs that fall outside limits using the function [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress
x_clipped = list(compress(x, mask))
y_clipped = list(compress(y, mask))
```

Demo:

```
In [117]: mask
Out[117]: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True]

In [118]: x_clipped
Out[118]: [-10, -10, 0, 10, 40]

In [119]: y_clipped
Out[119]: [-20, -10, 0, 20, 10]
```